# Multiple DNS with different records for one domain?

Tags: dns

I have a main domain (example-main.com) and i am using cloudflare dns for the dns, what i hope to know is it possible for me to have a completely different dns server to handle specific part of the records, in this case i have a webhotel using cpanel where i have multiple domains, and a dedicated server. What i hope to achieve is using the cpanel to handle *.dev.example-main.com, and use tha cloudflare to handel all other records, is it possible or do i need a secondary domain?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User! You can if you delegate the `dev.example-main.com` subdomain in Cloudflare to some other DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i hope to know is it possible for me to have a completely different dns server to handle specific part of the records

Yes, that's actually how your whole domain was set up to be handled by Cloudflare in the first place.

The usual term for this is a 'delegation', which you can create by adding `NS` records in Cloudflare that point to your other nameserver. (Note that those *must* point to the nameserver by name, not by IP address, so you'll also need A/AAAA records for the nameserver itself.)

```
dev.example.com.     NS    whserv.example.com.
whserv.example.com.  A     192.0.1.42
whserv.example.com.  AAAA  2001:db8:1::42
```

The point at which NS records are placed will basically become its own domain, so your CPanel DNS server needs to be configured with `dev.example.com` – not just `example.com` – as the domain name, to match the NS delegation. (Otherwise strange problems may occur.)

Delegations can be done at any level (e.g. you can delegate a sub-sub-sub-subdomain) except for the domain itself.